# Why code not working for configuring while loop

Tags: python

Why my code not working

a “game” where, through input, enter the number of players who will play the game, how to make so many inputs (for player nicknames) be displayed, how many players are playing? and how to do something to add all the nicknames to the array later?
For example: the host introduced what 5 people play, how to output 5 inputs and then add all the nicknames to the array?

```
print("Add players!")
plam = int(input("How many players will be? \n"))

playersNames = []
i = len(playersNames)
while i < plam:
    writePlayerName = input("Write player's nickname:   " + Fore.GREEN)
    print(Fore.WHITE)
    playersNames.append(writePlayerName)
    print(playersNames)
    break;
```

Problem statement

player names can be entered endlessly, but I here restricted that there will be 5 players

Comment: `break` will get you out of `while`.  You want to increase a counter by one at the end of while, or check that the length of playersNames < plam inside the while loop

Comment: Your while loop won't stop. You are neither updating `i` nor `plam` inside the loop. `i = len(playersNames)` is just `i = 0`, because at the moment of running it `playersNames` is an empty array

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
for i in range(plam):
    writePlayerName = input("Write player's nickname:   " + Fore.GREEN)
    print(Fore.WHITE)
    playersNames.append(writePlayerName)
print(playersNames)
```

Comment: Note, that you can use `_` here instead of `i`, because the value of `i` is never used in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `break;` statement is ending the while loop. You can remove the while loop and it should function as as you meant it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, but it is not doing what you want to do, because you missed some logical steps:

1. You only update `i` once outside the loop.
   `len` function will not make `i` magically track the length of `playerNames` it will only put current length when called in to `i` which is 0, because you call `len` when `playerNames` is empty.
2. You call `break` in the loop without condition, so your loop will always exit after the first time.

While there are several ways to write this code, and Andrea Pollini gave a good, clean example, here is the minimum fix to your code to do what you want:

```
print("Add players!")
plam = int(input("How many players will be? \n"))

playersNames = []

while i < plam:
    writePlayerName = input("Write player's nickname:   " + Fore.GREEN)
    print(Fore.WHITE)
    playersNames.append(writePlayerName)
    print(playersNames)
    i = len(playersNames)
```

Note, that all I did was to move the `len` call in to the loop, to where the `break` used to be.

Answer (score 0):

- Try this one

```
print("Add players!")
plam = int(input("How many players will be? \n"))

playersNames = []
i = len(playersNames)
for i in range(plam):
    writePlayerName = input("Write player's nickname:   " + Fore.GREEN)
    print(Fore.WHITE)
    playersNames.append(writePlayerName)
    print(playersNames)
```

- output

```
Add players!
How many players will be? 
3   
Write player's nickname:   jhon
['jhon']
Write player's nickname:   smith
['jhon', 'smith']
Write player's nickname:   roky
['jhon', 'smith', 'roky']
```